# Git pre-commit hook doesn't work in Windows

Tags: git

Pre-commit hooks just doesn't work in Windows. I tried all the possible ways found in this link: [Git hook not running on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032849/git-hook-not-running-on-windows)

I have my `pre-commit` file inside `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello, World!"
```

Steps I followed to test:

1. Updated a file
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit - m "test"`

I tried both `sh` and `bash` but still no luck. What could be wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: Windows isn't Linux so calling `/bin/bash` would result in an error. Try that on Powershell and you would see the error. Windows it should be on the `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`.

Comment: First, are you using a shell or the command prompt? just to make sure, check that `pre-commit` has execution permissions with `chmod +x pre-commit`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your pre-commit hook in a simple CMD, with git version 2.30.1.windows.1 (not even the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

It just works.
I even added an exit 1 (to *not* commit the test commit I was making)

But it does work (even on Windows, calling bash) if bash.exe is in your `%PATH%`

```sh
where bash
C:\path\to\git\bin\bash.exe
```

I am using the bash included in Git For Windows, even though recent Windows 10 do have their own `bash.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with husky pre-commit hook not working in GitHub Desktop client on Windows.

The error was:

> /usr/bin/env: 'bash': No such file of directory husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)

Was fixed by adding `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to PATH for current user and entire PC

Comment: So, the same conclusion as in my answer? Adding bin to the PATH?